# ¿Como validar que la ejecución de un insert se realizó?

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Estoy manejando Java con base de datos en Oracle.

```
updateRegistro(arrayBitRegistrosLlenado.get(i).getTabla_origen(), arrayBitRegistrosLlenado.get(i).getID_cuest_bit_ver());
/*
 * Bloque que a partir de la variable SQL, 
 * (contiene la sentencia insert generada anteriormente dentro del mismo metodo)
 * realiza el insert en la tabla correspondiente
 */
try {
    stmt = conexion.conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
    count_registros++;
    stmt.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.err.println("Error al insertar " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Anterior al código presentado, se genera el `insert` y lo guarda en la variable `SQL`, inmediatamente se llama a la función `update()` que recibe como parámetro el nombre de la tabla y un ID para realizar el update.

Quiero que solo se mande llamar 'update' cuando el registro se realizó, y no en todos los casos, aunque el `insert` contenga algún error de sintaxis dado que se generan automaticamente.

Comment: Podrías añadir el código de insert anterior?.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿De qué `update()` estás hablando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces operaciones de inserción, modificación, o eliminación, usualmente (es posible configurar para que no lo haga) se devuelve desde el gestor de base de datos el número de filas afectadas ( el número de filas insertadas, modificadas o eliminadas). Puedes utilizar ese número para saber si se insertaron o no datos en la base de datos (es decir, si el número es mayor a 0 sí hubo filas insertadas, si el número es igual a 0 no hubo filas insertadas).

Para éstas sentencias que no son consultas puedes utilizar stmt.**executeUpdate** (*[también se puede usar para insertar y eliminar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String))*) que devuelve el número de filas afectadas o 0 si tu sentencia no devuelve nada. executeQuery(SQL) es especial ejecutar una consulta y regresar un ResultSet (tabla de información).

Answer (score 1):

La opción fácil y no segura es que pongas un bolean, después de hacer el executeQuery() para insertar pones el el boleano en true y así sabes que insertó, La opcion recomendada es que uses un ResultSet.

```
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
```

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo, espero te sirva.
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaha/rsltdata.htm

Answer (score 1):

la interfaz PreparedStatement tiene un metodo llamado executeUpdate el cual retorna un valor entero para comprobar si se hizo el registro en la base de datos puedes probar :

```
        int resp = stm.executeUpdate();
        if (resp > 0) {
            System.out.println("objeto insertado");
        }
```